# preventing arrow keys's outputing raw characters like ^[[A when making a shell in C

Tags: c, shell

I am implementing a shell-like program where user types command (defined by me). Just like this.

```
>cmd
result blah blah blah
>
```

When I use arrow keys it outputs raw characters  like `^[[A`.

```
>^[[A
```

I also notice sqlite3 behaves like this at least in the version I compiled on my computer.

How to prevent this and let `<-` and `->` keys move cursor left and right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is a library specifically designed for this task (that is, allowing the user to edit commands typed at an interactive command-driven program).  Note that this library is distributed under the GPL (*not* the LGPL); if that won't work for you, [editline](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) is a similar library with a BSD-style license.

I note that you say this is homework, so you might want to ask your instructor whether you are expected to implement cursor motion and line editing yourself.  If so, ncurses (as mentioned by jDourlens) is the next step down in terms of abstraction, and if you *really* want to do everything yourself, read up on [termios](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/termios.html) and the [VT-220 control sequences](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/contents.html) (nearly all terminal emulators used nowadays emulate the VT220 or one of its descendants).

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-not-lgpl.html explains why GNU Readline is covered under GPL and not LGPL.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a slightly simpler way to do that. Run `rlwrap [your program]` instead of `[your program]`.

For example, it works fine with `sqlite3` as `rlwrap sqlite3`

Answer (score 2):

To let the user navigate in cmd with the keyboards arrows you may have to use `termcaps`.

http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_chapter/termcap_2.html

If you want to be easier to deal with termcaps that are a bit complex you shoul use `Ncurses`.

http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

Good luck to deal with termcaps if you chosse this solution, it's some pain in the ass!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look to [Ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). It's a library that let you control almost everything in terminals. The specific function you want is `noecho()`, which stops terminals from showing users' input.